# Database connection is not working - Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4, legacy-code

[image]

I am working in a legacy application which is developed with symfony 1.4. I am trying to setup the old symfony project in my computer. But when I am running the project I am getting the following issue. My database authentication has been provided in the database.yml file as the following.

```
   all
      doctrine:
          class: sfDoctrineDatabase
          param:
              dsn: 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=cirrenaivs'
              username: root
              password: my_secret_pw_shh
```

Appreciate someone's advice for this issue.

Comment: Have you installed the mysql driver locally?

Comment: No I haven't done that. I am using this project in the docker environment. I don't know how to do that. These are the versions of my applications inside my docker environment. "mysql:5.7 / php:7.2.2-apache"

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the PHP mysql extension. Depending which OS you're using, you can probably add something like `sudo yum install php-mysql` to your Dockerfile.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your response. Was able to fix the issue the way you have given as a solution.